# How do I change the innerText on the li element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, textnode

This code is after the browser's loaded. I need to change the `li` class `buddyName` - "Strider" to "Aragon".

```
<script src="./scripts/fellowship.js"></script>
<main>
    <section id="Middle-Earth">
        <article class="the-shire">...</article>
        <article class="rivendell">
            <h1>Rivendell</h1>
            <aside>
                <ul id="myBuddy">
                    <li class="buddyName">Gandalf the Grey</li>
                    <li class="buddyName">Legolas</li>
                    <li class="buddyName">Gimli</li>
                    <li class="buddyName">Strider</li>
                    <li class="buddyName">Boromir</li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
        </article>
        <article class="morder">...</article>
    </section>
</main>
```

This was my most recent attempt but not working:

```
document.querySelectorAll('buddyName'[3]).innerHTML = "Aragorn";
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.buddyName')[3]`

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 3):

You would use `getElementsByClassName` to get all `li` tags. The next step is select the fourth element of the array and change the value.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('buddyName')[3].innerHTML= "Aragorn";
```